# Al implementar un navigation drawer y listview, el navigation drawer no ejecuta ninguna acción

Tags: java, android, listview, android-drawerlayout

Intento implementar en una misma actividad un navigation drawer y un listview, pero el problema es que solo me funciona el lisview (listview1).

El listview del navigation drawer (listview2) no funciona: se despliega el menu pero **no ejecuta ninguna acción**.

Al parecer el método `listView2.setOnItemClickListener` no se ejecuta.

¿Cómo puedo hacer que funcione?

MainActivity class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private String[] opciones = new String[] {"opcion1", "opcion2", "opcion3","opcion4"};
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private ListView listView1;
private ListView listView2;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
int posicion;



private Productos[] datos = new Productos[]{
        new Productos(R.drawable.hamburguesa,20000,"Hamburguesa","Con papas y gaseosa"),
        new Productos(R.drawable.perro,12000,"Perro","Con tocineta"),
        new Productos(R.drawable.chusos,15000,"Chuzo","De res o de pollo"),
        new Productos(R.drawable.jugo,6000,"Jugo","En agua o en leche")
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Adapter adaptador = new Adapter(this, datos);

    listView2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);


    listView2.setAdapter(adaptador);

    listView2.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"presiono "+i,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("producto presionado", ((Productos)adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i)).getNombre());
        }
    });



    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null){
        actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu_white_24dp);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.contenedorPrincipal);
    listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.menuIzq);

    listView1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, opciones));

    listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            switch (i){
                case(0):
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "presiono 1",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case(1):
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "presiono 2",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case(2):
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "presiono 3",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case(3):
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "presiono 4",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }

            listView1.setItemChecked(i,true);
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(listView1);
        }
    });

    drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,R.string.abierto, R.string.cerrado);

    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);



}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case android.R.id.home:
            drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}




class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<Productos> {
    public Adapter(Context context, Productos[] datos) {
        super(context, R.layout.producto_item, datos);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        View item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.producto_item, null);

        ImageView imagen = (ImageView) item.findViewById(R.id.iImagen);
        imagen.setImageResource(datos[position].getIdImagen());

        TextView nombre = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.tNombre);
        nombre.setText(datos[position].getNombre());
        TextView descripcion = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.tDescripcion);
        descripcion.setText(datos[position].getDescripcion());
        TextView precio = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.tPrecio);
        precio.setText(String.valueOf(datos[position].getPrecio()));


        return (item);
    }
}

}
```

MainActivity Layout

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

android:id="@+id/contenedorPrincipal"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<ListView
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/menuIzq"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:foregroundGravity="left"
    android:layout_gravity="start">
</ListView>


<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView">
</ListView>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Productos class

```
public class Productos {

int idImagen, precio;
String nombre, descripcion;

public Productos(int idImagen, int precio, String nombre, String descripcion) {
    this.idImagen = idImagen;
    this.precio = precio;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.descripcion = descripcion;
}

public String getDescripcion() {
    return descripcion;
}

public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
    this.descripcion = descripcion;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public int getPrecio() {
    return precio;
}

public void setPrecio(int precio) {
    this.precio = precio;
}

public int getIdImagen() {
    return idImagen;
}

public void setIdImagen(int idImagen) {
    this.idImagen = idImagen;
}
}
```

Productos Layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="120dp">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:id="@+id/iImagen"
    android:src="@drawable/hamburguesa"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:text="Hamburguesa"
        android:id="@+id/tNombre"
        android:textColor="@color/black"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Con papas y gaseosa"
        android:id="@+id/tDescripcion"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:text="20000"
        android:id="@+id/tPrecio"
        android:textColor="@color/red"
        android:gravity="right"/>

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Agrega en tu `ListView` la propiedad  `android:choiceMode="singleChoice"`, con eso debe funcionar:

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:id="@+id/listView">
</ListView>
```

Comment: gracias por responder. pero nada no soluciona el problema ademas el listview que esta por fuera del navigation drawer si funciona, el problema es con el listview que despliega el menu del navigation drawer.